# conversion operator with template functions

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a class with a conversion operator to `std::string`. It works great with everything except with functions receiving `std::basic_string<T>` (templated on `T`).

```
#include <string>
struct A{
  operator std::string(){return std::string();}
};

void F(const std::basic_string<char> &){}
template<typename T> void G(const std::basic_string<T> &) {}

int main(){
  A a;
  F(a); // Works!
  G(a); // Error!
  return 0; // because otherwise I'll get a lot of comments :)
}
```

The error I receive is

```
error: no matching function for call to 'G(A&)'                                     
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T> void G(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)
```

Now, I know I can define `G` as a friend in the struct `A` and it'll work, but my problem is with a lot of stl functions that already exist and receive `std::basic_string<T>` (for example, the `operator<<` printing function, or comparison operators, or many other functions.

I would really like to be able to use `A` as if it was an `std::string`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The problem is that T needs to be deduced for `G` and that it doesn't work like that (taking conversion functions into account). `G<char>(a);` will work, but I suppose that's not what you want.

Comment: Yea, `G((std::string)a)` also works but both of those don't really cut it. I want something that'll be shorter / better than just adding an `str()` member function instead of the conversion operator

Comment: You are better off making a ToString method.

Comment: @NeilKirk - sure, but that means the conversion operator is useless in many cases. Worse, it means I can't use a conversion operator at all (even for non-template functions) because it'll be confusing for the user of the class that sometimes he has to use the `ToString` method and sometimes he doesn't.

Comment: `return 0; // because otherwise I'll get a lot of comments :)` You may get more for including it. It's redundant, so I'd omit it.

Comment: @cluracan conversion operator is best avoided completely. It will be less confusing for the user to use ToString that always works than something that doesn't

Comment: @NeilKirk - nothing is "best avoided completely" (except maybe `goto`). In some cases conversion operators are exactly what you need. Just like overloading `operator+` is more useful than using a `sum` function. It's true that if something doesn't work well (like here) it's basically useless - but the need still exists.

Comment: @cluracan Ironically, goto is considered acceptable to exit nested loops!

Comment: @BoBTFish By many. Ask a Question if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I would really like to be able to use A as if it was an `std::string`. Is there any way to do this?

Yes, but are you sure you really want this? The solution is:

```
struct A : public std::string {
};
```

but recall that `std::string` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor and therefore, cannot be used polymorphically. **You have been warned!!!**

A `str()` is a far better solution and allows you to be explicit when you want to pass your `A` to a function taking a `std::basic_string<T>`.

Comment: That is actually an interesting option. I don't intend to use it polymorphically, and to be honest this isn't really what I want / need - but I'll have to think maybe I can make it work! **Edit** - is it possible to make it inherit from a `const std::string`?

Comment: @cluracan you can't inherit from a "const" something.

Comment: @NeilKirk - too bad :( because it's exactly what I'd want here... (maybe, haven't really thought this through yet)

Comment: @cluracan You will go through many complicated and ugly ideas until you realize some things aren't worth the bother and ToString it is ;)

Comment: @NeilKirk - That's the solution I currently use (although I call it `str`, as it's shorter and that's what `stl` uses). I just really hoped there's something I don't know. It's sad that these kinks still exist in C++ where just because you wanted to make something "more general" (`string` templated on the `char`) you lose functionality (being able to do an `operator string`)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot infer that far; you'll either have to explicitly call the cast operator or to explictly specify the template parameter :

```
G(static_cast<std::string>(a));
G<char>(a);
```

To understand why the compiler can't do both user-defined conversion and template argument deduction, let's take this example :

```
template<typename T>
struct Number {
    Number(double n) {};
    Number(int n) {};
};

struct A{
  operator Number<double>(){return Number<double>(1.);}
  operator Number<int>(){return Number<int>(1);}
};

template<typename T> void G(Number<T>& number) { }

int main(){
  A a;
  G(a); // What do I do ?!
  return 0;
}
```

What the compiler should do in that case ?

Comment: But both of these options are worse (uglier) than using a specific `str()` member function for the conversion. So in a real sense, this lack makes conversion operators almost useless (for template things like `string`). Is there really no way around this?

Comment: About your edit - not a good example. Now there are 2 options, and the compiler should say "hey, there are two options!" like it always does when there are two options (even for non-template stuff and conversions that work completely like `int` and `long`). The problem is that although there is an option in my case, the compiler finds 0 options.

Comment: @cluracan There is just not enough constraints for the compiler to perform a simple one-level deduction. And making the compiler do multiple levels inference would have a lot of side effects.

Answer (score 1):

User defined conversions are not taken into consideration when performing template argument deduction.

Explicit specialization of `G` will work.

```
G<char>(a);
```